# \citetitle and \citeeditor using the natbib & hyperref packages

Tags: hyperref, natbib

I am very much committed to the `natbib` package, but still want to cite different fields of my bibliography items. For this I am using [this code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/F_ODZZJCCKg) found in a google forum.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{author00,
title = {{A Title}},
publisher = {Alpha},
year = {2008},
editor = {Author, A},
address = {London}
}
@book{buthor00,
title = {{B Title}},
publisher = {Bravo},
year = {1990},
author = {Buthor, B},
address = {New York}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{keyval}

\input{https://groups.google.com/forum}% symbolically, for readability's sake 
\newbibfield{editor}
\bibinput{mytestbib}

\begin{document}
\usebibentry{author00}{editor} has edited `\usebibentry{author00}{title}'

\citeauthor{buthor00} has written `\usebibentry{buthor00}{title}'
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mytestbib}
\end{document}
```

This results in

[image]

and poses problems I cannot solve:

1. I would like `\usebibentry{author00}{editor}` to result in 'Author', analog to `\citeauthor{buthor00}`
2. Is it possible to have the `\usebibentry{key}{field}` also create a hyperlink, analog to `\citeauthor`?
3. *%% LaTeX2e file `mytestbib.bib' ...* is being put into the document and causes an error, can that be avoided?
4. The bibitem 'author00' does not appear in 'References' (a minor problem, since also `\cite`d regularly in my document)

> **Below is an amendment in response to egreg's answer**

JabRef produces .bib files that look in principle the same as if produced by `\begin{filecontents}`, i.e.

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.7.
% Encoding: Cp1252

@book{author00,
title = {{A Title}},
publisher = {Alpha},
year = {2008},
editor = {Author, A},
address = {London}
}
@book{buthor00,
title = {{B Title}},
publisher = {Bravo},
year = {1990},
author = {Buthor, B},
address = {New York}
}
```

My question regarding the hyperlink was imprecise, indeed. It should point at the entry in the 'References', which I now create as follows:

```
\newcommand{\editorlastname}[1]{\nocite{#1}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\usebibentry{#1}{editor}}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\removename\x\removename}
\def\removename#1,#2\removename{#1}
```

By the way, the `\editorlastname` works fine for me, but in case of multiple editors only the first editor is printed. (Should that be of importance to another user)

Comment: 1. This seems to be exactly the output you request, so I don't follow; 3. Use the `filecontents*` environment together with the [`filecontents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) - so put that in your preamble, not before `\documentclass`; 4. Try adding `\nocite{author00}` in your document.

Comment: 1. Author has edited 'A Title' - is what I would prefer to read 3. That's neat, didn't know that. However, I am using JabRef and JabRef puts some comment in the beginning of my bibfiles as well, this was just for illustration.

Comment: The code you copied is now available as the package `usebib`.

Comment: In my test the commented initial lines *are* ignored.

Comment: Yes, same here. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `filecontents*` environment when you want to output a `.bib` file, so the initial commented lines are omitted. However this should not be a problem when you use the relatively new [`usebib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/usebib) package, which is derived from the `comp.text.tex` code you mention.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{author00,
title = {{A Title}},
publisher = {Alpha},
year = {2008},
editor = {Author, A},
address = {London}
}
@book{buthor00,
title = {{B Title}},
publisher = {Bravo},
year = {1990},
author = {Buthor, B},
address = {New York}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{keyval}

\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{editor}
\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\usebibentry{author00}{editor} has edited `\usebibentry{author00}{title}'

\citeauthor{buthor00} has written `\usebibentry{buthor00}{title}'

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Note that I've used `\jobname` as the name of the `.bib` file, just not to clutter my (already overcluttered) directory of examples. Any name is just as good.

To get the last name, when the editor is stated in the `.bib` file in the form

```
lastname, firstname
```

you can say in your preamble

```
\newcommand{\editorlastname}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\usebibentry{#1}{editor}}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\removename\x\removename}
\def\removename#1,#2\removename{#1}
```

and then use `\editorlastname{author00}`. For hyperlinks one should know what to point at.

Comment: A very useful package which should be promoted more prominently around here! However, the output doesn't change, so my initial problems remain - i.e using editors full name instead of last name only, no hyperlinks created and errors due to .bib file preceding comments (e.g. produced by JabRef). Is there a work-around?

Comment: @D.Roepo The package doesn't even try to parse author or editor names: coping with BibTeX syntax on the LaTeX side is quite complicated. I'll try getting only the last name. Can you add a real example of a JabRef generated file that gives problems?

Comment: Do you know how I can find out what the labels for the bibentries are? Then something like this `\hyperref[*label*]{\editorlastname{author00}}` could be used.

Comment: @D.Roepo You can use `\hyperlink{cite.author00}{\editorlastname{author00}}`. However, `\citeauthor` works also with editors, so `\citeauthor{author00}` is the best way, if there's no author in the entry.

Comment: @egreg Do you think it is possible to find a way around the "only lowercase field name" limitation of the package? Because BibDesk creates the field names with capital first letters and putting `\newbibfield{Title}` in the preamble does not work.

Comment: @HalilŞEN Add `\newbibfield{Title}`, but then do `\usebibentry{author00}{title}`; field names are normalized to lowercase for `\usebibentry`.

Comment: @egreg I don't know why but this didn't work when I first try it. I was reading the `usebib.sty` to see what is going on but now it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for posting this problem. I am facing similar problem. I also want to print only title field using BibTeX. But the example that you posted not working in my case.

Comment: @user93268 Please, ask a new question with a non working example.