# How to write the authors full name and avoid style formatting given by biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, author, abnt, mfirstuc

The ABNT style uses uppercase for authors family name. When citing an author named *John Doe* and year *2021*, it gives *(DOE, 2021)*. I want to get the authors full name, so I followed the solution provided by @loved-by-Jesus in [Cite Author's Full Name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85966/cite-authors-full-name). It is not enough, since ABNT style formats the family name in uppercase, resulting in *John DOE* instead of the intended *John Doe*. I tried to use `\capitalisewords` from `mfirstuc` package, but it did not work out.

Here is the sample code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=abnt,ittitles]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\newrobustcmd*{\citefirstlastauthor}{\AtNextCite{\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}}\citeauthor}
\newcommand\theauthorname[1]{\capitalisewords{\expandafter\citefirstlastauthor*{#1}}}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{doe2021,
  author = {John Doe and Mary White and Cris Ross},
  title = {Author Title Test},
  journal = {Test Journal},
  year = {2021}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{author} 
\newbibfield{address} 
\bibinput{test}
\begin{document}
\theauthorname{doe2021}\\
\textcite{doe2021}\\
\usebibentry{doe2021}{author}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

The solution provided by @nicholas-hamilton in [How to cite full author name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120190/how-to-cite-full-author-name), uses `usebib` package, which gives you almost the correct text (since it keeps the connecting words *and* instead of using comma, and does not translate it when the document is in a different language), and it also does not create the link to the bibliography.

How to get the full names *John Doe, Mary White e Cris Ross* and still link it to the bibliography?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `biblatex-abnt` modifies the name macros quite a bit, we need some code to reverse some of those changes. `\textcite` does not capitalise the names, so I hunted down the required code from there.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=abnt,ittitles]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citefirstlastauthor}
  {\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}%
   \let\multinamedelim\multinamedelimorig
   \let\finalnamedelim\finalnamedelimorig
   \let\mkbibnamefamily\origmkbibnamefamily
   \let\mkbibnamegiven\origmkbibnamegiven
   \let\mkbibnameprefix\origmkbibnameprefix
   \let\mkbibnamesuffix\origmkbibnamesuffix
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\ifciteindex%
     {\indexnames{labelname}}%
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}%
  {\multicitedelim}%
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}%

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe2021,
  author = {John Doe and Mary White and Cris Ross},
  title = {Author Title Test},
  journal = {Test Journal},
  year = {2021}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citefirstlastauthor{doe2021}

\textcite{doe2021}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: John Doe, Mary White e Cris Ross]