# How to cite a title with natbib?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have searched far and wide after a solution, but haven't found one that works. 
The most prominent ones looks like: 
[\citetitle and \citeeditor using the natbib & hyperref packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53662/citetitle-and-citeeditor-using-the-natbib-hyperref-packages)
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496599/how-do-i-cite-the-title-of-an-article-in-latex

My relevant setup is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliographystyle{myabbrvnat}
\newcommand{\myand}{\&\ }
\setcitestyle{authoryear,aysep={},open={(},close={)}}
\begin{document}
In the book (Book Name) such and such is told to be true \citep{RefWorks:}.
\bibliography{cource}
\end{document}
```

with my source.bib-file looking like:

```
@book{RefWorks:1
     author={John Johnson},
     year={2015},
     title={Book Name},
     publisher={Publishing Company},
     address={United States of America},
     edition={1st},
     isbn={XXX-X-XXXX-XXXX-X}
}
```

Probably the reason why some of the suggestions that I have found won't work is the `\bibliographystyle{myabbrvnat}`. I can't remember where I found it, but it's to setup my bibliography the way I need it. Is that important? If needed to be posted, where can I post the text, since it goes over the character limit here?

I know there is a "sort of" solution, where I can make a citation aliasing like `\defcitealias{RefWorks:1}{Book Name}` and then insert it in the text like `\citetalias{RefWorks:1}` to give the title of the source. It's fine, but it's not what I'm looking for, because then I would need to set this up for my whole library, which would get tiresome.

Is there a way to setup a `\cite+`-type to give the title of a source?

Edit: I forgot to put hyperref package in my setup.

Comment: You should use `biblatex` and `biber` for this kind of job. Or, with traditional methods, you can look at the `usebib` package, as explained in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: I have tried, but if I switch, then it goes back to use "and" when there are two authors. I need "&" to indicate that, which I have with my current setup.

Comment: Did you try with `usebib`, then?

Comment: It would be useful to know *where* `&` should be used instead of `and`.

Comment: If I use \usepackage{usebib} with \citetitle{RefWorks:1} I get a Compile error.

Comment: on the note of "&" and "and" I need to use "&" both in text and in the bibliography, since I write in two different languages, where "and" is only used in English, but "&" is used in both of them.

Comment: So you'd like that, in case of multiple authors, their names are separated by `&` in the bibliography? This is pretty unclear from your example, in addition to the fact that you refer to an unspecified `myabbrvnat` style.

Comment: almost yes. In case of more than 2 authors it says "et al.". The "myabbrvnat"-file almost looks like this: http://gallium.inria.fr/~remy/latex/plainnat.bst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified `abbrvnat.bst` to issue `\myand{}` instead of `and` (changing the places where `" and "` appears). Then prepared this input file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{RefWorks:1,
     author={John Johnson},
     year={2015},
     title={Book Name},
     publisher={Publishing Company},
     address={United States of America},
     edition={1st},
     isbn={XXX-X-XXXX-XXXX-X}
}
@book{RefWorks:2,
     author={John Johnson and Jack Jackson},
     year={2015},
     title={Book Name},
     publisher={Publishing Company},
     address={United States of America},
     edition={1st},
     isbn={XXX-X-XXXX-XXXX-X}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands,article]{memoir}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{usebib}
\bibliographystyle{myabbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,aysep={},open={(},close={)}}
\bibinput{\jobname} % <--- the same argument as in \bibliography
\newcommand{\myand}{\&}

\begin{document}

In the book ``\usebibentry{RefWorks:1}{title}'' by 
\citeauthor{RefWorks:1}, such and such is told 
to be true \citep{RefWorks:1}.

In the book ``\usebibentry{RefWorks:2}{title}'' by 
\citeauthor{RefWorks:2}, such and such is told 
to be true \citep{RefWorks:2}.

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

This is the output

[image]

Note that `filecontents` is used just for convenience and you can use your own `.bib` file. Rememeber the limitation of `usebib` that fields *must* be delimited with braces and not with `"`.

On the other hand, one can coerce `biblatex` into producing the desired output:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{RefWorks:1,
     author={John Johnson},
     year={2015},
     title={Book Name},
     publisher={Publishing Company},
     address={United States of America},
     edition={1st},
     isbn={XXX-X-XXXX-XXXX-X}
}
@book{RefWorks:2,
     author={John Johnson and Jack Jackson},
     year={2015},
     title={Book Name},
     publisher={Publishing Company},
     address={United States of America},
     edition={1st},
     isbn={XXX-X-XXXX-XXXX-X}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands,article]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,firstinits,uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \DeclareNameAlias{author}{first-last}%
}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\&\space
}

\begin{document}

In the book ``\citetitle{RefWorks:1}'' by 
\citeauthor{RefWorks:1}, such and such is told 
to be true \parencite{RefWorks:1}.

In the book ``\citetitle{RefWorks:2}'' by 
\citeauthor{RefWorks:2}, such and such is told 
to be true \parencite{RefWorks:2}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked using your setup and placing \usebibentry{RefWorks:1}{title} in the text. My only question is (and I forgot to mention this, but I have edited my original entry to use hyperref) why is \usebibentry{RefWorks:1}{title} not an active reference, that I can click on, so it takes my to the bibliography, as if I have used \citep{RefWorks:1} ?

Comment: @user38934 Because it isn't. Sorry, but I'm not interested in adding the feature.